# GIT Removing FETCH refs from remote tracking

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, egit

I am new to using **GIT** in **eclipse** i have been playing around with the tool and i did several **push** and **merges** to the server however i am seeing in the **Remote Tracking** option when i do a **fetch** i am getting **branches** i do not need or use anymore. How can i remove from **Remote Tracking**, branches i do not need anymore.

I attempted a delete however when i do a **fetch** again from the server they all come back. I also need these **branch** names however i cannot reuse them since they already exist. Under is a screen shot of what i see when i attempt to configure the FETCH option.

**GIT FETCH CONFIGURATION**

[image: GIT FETCH CONFIGURATION]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete those branches on the server as well as locally:

```
git push --delete origin <branchName>
```

(As in "[How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309)")

If you don't, the next fetch will bring those branches back.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the default refspecs to fetch from a remote:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

(likewise with `remote.origin.push`).  Then delete the unwanted branches locally and fetch won't reload them unless you specifically ask.